# jquery filtered elements moved between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm bulding small filtering feature for items listed in div elements. These div elements are in a slider placed next to each other. 
So each column contains a number of items. The filtering is working but i can't find a way to group the filtered items one under another so they would be in a first colum, not in their oryginal column:

```
<input id="filter" name="filter" size="40"/>

<div class="filtered">        
    <div class="archive-col-1 column">
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Alchemy</div></div>
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Balboa</div></div>
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Nebula</div></div>
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Radio</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="archive-col-2 column">
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Mathematics</div></div> 
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Disco</div></div>
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Antwon</div></div>   
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Barracuda</div></div>            
    </div>
    <div class="archive-col-3 column">
        <div class="name"><div class="element">English</div></div>
        <div class="name"><div class="element">France</div></div>
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Nairobi</div></div>  
        <div class="name"><div class="element">Crazy</div></div>    
    </div>    
</div>

function filter(element) {

    $("#filter").keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val(); 
        count = 0;

        $(".column .element").each(function () {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var length = $(this).text().length > 0;
            if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                parent.hide();
            } else {
                parent.show();
                //appendTo.closest('.colums');
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
}

$('input').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
});
```

- example: http://jsfiddle.net/pw7k2/

In my another example filtering works fine but I don't know how to limit rows and move other filtered items to the next column, now they go to first column only:

http://jsfiddle.net/yQD7X/

Did anyone have similar problem?

Comment: I think this is more of a CSS question.  I'm not 100% sure why you want different columns in the HTML.  Anything for styling should go in the CSS, and the HTML should be for content data only.  Meaning… if you don't always want multiple columns… don't hard code multiple columns into the HTML.

Comment: adding a keyup event handler inside another keyup event handler doesn't seem like a very good idea ?

Comment: @Dan Goodspeed,
these columns are pulled dynamically and they have to be multiple, so i have to base on what is hardcoded. Here is updated example with separated CCS

Comment: @adeneo True, I updated it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pw7k2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pw7k2/2/

```
function dispatchElements() {
    var $elements = $('.column .element:visible').remove();
    var $column = $('.column:first');

    $elements.each(function(index, value) {
        var height = $column.height();
        var $childrens = $column.children(':visible');
        var childrenHeight = 0;

        $childrens.each(function(){
            childrenHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
        });

        childrenHeight += childrenHeight/$childrens.length;

        if (childrenHeight > height) {
            $column = $column.next();
        }

        $(this).appendTo($column);
    });
}
```

This method removes all visible elements and dispatch them after checking if there's available space in the current column, if not it takes the next one.

Comment: np ;) please validate my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Do you mean to vote up? I can't because it requiers that I need to have 15 reputation points - and I have just one :(